# .map() undefined even though I pass an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mobx

I'm trying to map an array in my Component render method but it keeps saying `.map is not a function` even though it's an array.

```
return (
  <select className="c-select">
    <option value="">Choose your city</option>
      {console.log(state.cities.items)}
      {state.cities.items.map(city => <option key={city.slug} value={city.slug}>{city.name}</option>)}
  </select>
);
```

The console log gives me this result:

> [{"id":1,"name":"Berlin","country":"Germany","default":1,"slug":"berlin"},{"id":2,"name":"Hamburg","country":"Germany","default":0,"slug":"hamburg"}]

I have no clue why `.map` is undefined - Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Chrome or Firefox, it looks like `state.cities.items` is a JSON string, not an Array.

Try

```
{JSON.parse(state.cities.items).map(...)}
```

When you `console.log` real Arrays, the output will look like `Array [ Object, Object ]` in Firefox or `>[Object]` in Chrome

Comment: ... it's too late, I need to go to sleep. Thanks 